# How to get current user data from firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm working on an Ionic 4 Project, where I want to display all the posts from the current user once the user log into the application. Currently, I'm using `snapshotChanges()` and `subscribe()` method (as shown below) to get the data from firestore. But it gives me every single data from the firestore document. Having the `userID` and `postID` references on both document, how can I get the value of `author` and `desc` from that specific user or is it possible? 
To be specific, how can I display user`(6YbhQux2sgTH66F0cJpdcT87Pw83)`'s post `(54d039ec-5b3c-4ee9-95a0-418b06365f25)` that contains `author` and `desc`?

Firestore: [firestore image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkpcA.png)

Here's what I did:

**getData.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
export class getData { 
    constructor(
      private firestore: AngularFirestore
    ) { }

    readData() {     
      return this.firestore.collection('promotions').snapshotChanges();
    }
}
```

**post.ts**

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.page.scss'],
})
export class PostPage implements OnInit {
 constructor(
     private afs: AngularFirestore
 ){}


ngOnInit() {

this.getData.readData().subscribe(data => {

  this.posts = data.map(e => {

    return {
      id: e.payload.doc.id,
      Author: e.payload.doc.data()['author'],
      Description: e.payload.doc.data()['desc'],
    };

  })
  console.log(this.posts);
 });
 }
}
```

**post.html**

```
<ion-card no-padding *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{post.Author}}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>{{ post.Description }}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

I also tried using `afAuth.auth.currentUser` to get the current user id and the posts but it shows an error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'DocumentSnapshot'`. I am new to this and not sure how to proceed.

```
let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
uid = user.uid;

this.afs.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get()
    .then(doc=>{
       var a = doc.data().posts
       console.log(a);
       this.afs.firestore.collection('posts').doc()
       .get().then(doc2=>{
         this.promotions = doc2.map(e=>{
           return {
             id: e.payload.doc2.id,
             Author: e.payload.doc2.data()['author'],
             Description: e.payload.doc2.data()['desc'],
           };
         })
     })
  })
```

**UPDATE**

```
let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
uid = user.uid;

   const docs = this.afs.collection('users');
     const userinfo = docs.snapshotChanges()
     .pipe( 
       map(actions => 
         actions.map(a => 
           { const data = 
             a.payload.doc.data(); 
             const id = a.payload.doc.id; 
             const Author = a.payload.doc.data()['author']
             return { id, data, Author
           }; 
        })
       ) 
     );
     console.log(userinfo);
```

Output: [userInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQonQ.png)

Comment: Hi @CODEr, based on the screenshot, I am not too sure if you are accessing your data correctly. I think you may need to double check your reference that points to the document you are trying to access. If you are fetching data from `posts` collection, and the ultimate goal is to get the `author` and `desc` fields. You will need to reference your `postID` document, so you have access to those fields. On the other hand, when accessing `users` collection, and trying to access the `posts` map, which contains a `0` field, you will need to decide which `userID` document. You need to know documentID.

Comment: @sllopis Hi, what I am trying to get is the `posts` collection field `author` and `desc` that user `(6YbhQux2sgTH66F0cJpdcT87Pw83)` had generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the "author" and "desc" of the posts that were created by a user, you could do the following:

```
let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
uid = user.uid;


this.afs.firestore.collection('posts').where('user', '==', uid).get().then(posts => {
  postsCreatedByUser = posts.docs.map(e => {
    return {
      Author: e.data()['author'],
      Description: e.data()['desc'],
    };
  }))
})
```

Note that, in order to filter the posts, I use the .where() method

Answer (score 0):

To get the `author` and `desc`, try the following:

```
let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
uid = user.uid;

const docs = this.afs.collection('users');
    const userInfo = docs.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(data => {
        return {
          id: data.payload.doc.id,
          Author: data.payload.doc.data()['author']
          Description: data.payload.doc.data()['desc']
        };
      }));
```

It seems you are using [`angularfire`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire), first put the reference at the document `userid` then using `snapshotChanges`, which returns an `Observable`, you can then retrieve the data. [`Pipe`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pipe) is an instance method in the `Observable` class that is used to stitch together functional operators into a chain (`map` is one of those operators).

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it shows an error `Property 'snapshotChanges' does not exist on type 'DocumentReference'`

Comment: What is `afs` in your code, it should be of type `AngulareFirestore` https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#using-angularfirestoredocument

Comment: Hi, it is AngularFirestore. My code `import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore'` and `private afs: AngularFirestore`

Comment: Getting this error `Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'DocumentChangeAction<unknown>[]'`

Comment: try `docs.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );`

Comment: Hi, based on your code above, how do I get the `author` and `desc` field?

Comment: Hi what are you getting inside 'data`?